# matplotlib: squashed subplots when using FigureCanvasTkAgg

Tags: python, canvas, matplotlib, tkinter

I'm trying to plot data from multiple files in a Tk window. Following the user_interfaces example for Tk I create my Figure() then create a FigureCanvasTkAgg with that figure and my root Tk window. If I grab the size of my figure (using get_size_inches or bbox.bounds) the height seems right and matches the height of the underlying Tk canvas. However, when the window comes up, the Figure is about half the size of the underlying Tk canvas and all the subplots are squashed together in that space. I can't for the life of me figure out how to make the Figure expand to the size of the Tk canvas or, indeed, even the size the Figure itself reports.

**Update**
If I save the plot_figure created by plt.subplots to a png file, it is the size specified in 'figsize'. When it's displayed, it is the size of the root window created with 'Tk()' rather than the size of the figure bbox or the canvas.

Here's the basic code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from Tkinter import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg

tk_root = Tk()
tk_root.wm_title("Embedding in Tk")

scrollbar = Scrollbar(tk_root)
scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

plot_count = 0

plot_figure,ax = plt.subplots(len(gpx_files), 1, figsize=(12, 3 * len(gpx_files)))
plot_figure.tight_layout()

for axes in ax:
        plt.sca(axes)

        plot_count += 1

        axes.plot(accum[20:-21], pace, linestyle="-")

        axes.set_ylim(0,22)
        axes.grid(True, which='major', axis='both')

canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(plot_figure, master=tk_root)
w,h = plot_figure.get_size_inches()
canvas.get_tk_widget().config(width=(12 * plot_figure.dpi), height=(h * (plot_figure.dpi)), bg='blue')
canvas.get_tk_widget().config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
canvas.get_tk_widget().config(scrollregion=(0,0, 12 * plot_figure.dpi, h * plot_figure.dpi))
scrollbar.config(command=canvas.get_tk_widget().yview)
canvas.show()
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand=1)
canvas._tkcanvas.pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand=1)

mainloop()
```

Comment: don't import pylab if you want to do serious GUI work and especially never `from pylab import *`

Comment: Well, yeah. This is prototype code from the matplotlib examples. But if I can't get this to work, what does it matter if I include the whole world?

Comment: What is the link you copied this from? And in matters what you import because `pyplot` has some global state which can break things if you are unlucky.

Comment: I got the pylab thing from here: [link](http://scipy-lectures.github.io/intro/matplotlib/matplotlib.html). I guess I crossed tutorials. I'll change the code example to match the last thing I tried.

Comment: Forgot the link to the Tk example I used: [Tk Tutorial](http://matplotlib.org/examples/user_interfaces/embedding_in_tk.html)

Comment: ever find a solution to this?